# Printing the elements in a linked-list

Tags: c++, algorithm

If I have a linked-list of ints, how can I iterate / travel through the linked-list so that I can print each element with cout in C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, your linked list has the typical linked list operations. These include getting an iterator that refers to the first element, incrementing the iterator to refer to the next element, checking if the iterator has run off the end of the list, and so on. The algorithm is:

1. Set an iterator to refer to the first element in the linked list.
2. If the iterator has run off the end of the linked list, stop.
3. Print the element the iterator refers to.
4. Increment the iterator.
5. Go to step 2.

If you don't know how to do any of these specific steps, then you don't know how to use the particular linked class you have. To help you with that, we'd need to see its code (or a link to its documentation if it's an off-the-shelf class).

A typical C++ implementation would look something like this:

```
void LinkedList::print(ostream& stream) const
{
      LinkedListElement* ptr = head; // this is my step 1
      while (ptr != NULL)            // this is my step 2
      {
           stream << *ptr;           // this is my step 3
           ptr = ptr->getNext();     // this is my step 4
      } // step 5 happens here because this is a loop
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps!

```
struct Node
    {
         int data;
         struct Node *next;
    }

void Print(Node *head)
{
    Node *a =head;
    while(a!=NULL){
        cout<<a->data<<endl;
        a = a->next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
void print(node* n) {
  cout << n -> value << endl;
  if(n -> next) print(n -> next);
}
```

and call it like this:

```
int main() {
  linked_list l;
  ...
  print(l -> head);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: okay. One problem the function is declared a certain way so in the .h file, which I can not edit, so what I have so far is: void Set::display( ostream& Out ) const{ /*...*/ }

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I don't know how I could convert that into a function that has a parametre / argument of type ostream.

Comment: How have you implemented the linked list?

Comment: The code he gave uses tail recursion. You can change it to iteration by using a loop instead of the code calling itself. (See my answer which shows the same algorithm converted to an iterative form.)